# Does Java Lombok have an annotation to create a function which resets all class properties to their default values, empty or null?

Tags: java, class, annotations, reset, lombok

I'm wondering if instead of creating my own clear function on a Java class which resets all my fields. If the Lombok project has a annotation which would create a reset function that resets each class property.

If not, is there another library that provides this?

Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't; the normal approach is to create a new copy. Why do you want to reset an existing instance?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am using this parser(https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser/blob/master/README-Java.md) and the documentation recommends i reuse the instance because of the GC cycles when parsing large apache access.log files.

Comment: To be honest, that documentation sounds like uninformed folk wisdom. The JVM GC system has been extensively tuned to be very efficient with _exactly_ this kind of short-lived object.

Comment: The golden rule of performance: Don't microoptimize for it until you have actually measured a performance problem. It's normal for a typical Web request in a Java application to create and then immediately discard *thousands* of objects, and the system is built to handle it.